# What is wrong with the custom method in DetailView

Tags: python, django, class, view, attributeerror

I am trying to compare the PK in the URL with the request.user.id so that no one can view other's profile. This might not be the conventional way to do it, but I'd still like to know what is wrong with my code. I'm a new learner so bear with me.

## views.py

```
class UserDetail(DetailView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    template_name = 'details.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.id != self.kwargs['pk']:
            queryset = Profile.objects.first()
            return queryset
        else:
            return self.queryset
```

## models.py

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^details/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(views.UserDetail.as_view())),
```

When I go to the URL:

**ERROR**

```
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:   'Profile' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Profile instance is not a queryset.

You shouldn't be overriding `get_queryset`, you should be overriding [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object), which returns the specific object you want to display.

Comment: Clarifying, perhaps: `Profile.objects.first()` does not return a queryset, it returns the first object (or None) from the query. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#first